Dataform workflow "compilationResult" doesn't return error when compiled queries interface give error
I have the following workflow:
main:
    steps:
    - init:
        assign:
        - repository: projects/{project_id}/locations/{region}/repositories/{repo}
    - createCompilationResult:
        call: http.post
        args:
            url: ${"https://dataform.googleapis.com/v1beta1/" + repository + "/compilationResults"}
            auth:
                type: OAuth2
            body:
                gitCommitish: main
        result: compilationResult
    - complete:
        return: ${compilationResult.body}

When executing this workflow It is not returning any error (code 200). However I know that the main branch of this repo contains a compilation error that I've purposely created.
What is the purpose of this step exactly? Is it expected to not return any compilation error even when there is a mistake in my SQL preventing the repo to properly compile? Do I need to run the createWorkflowInvocation step to catch the error?

According to the API documentation here, you'll see any compilation errors in the "compilationErrors" node of the response json you receive from this call. So to check for errors you'd need to unpack the result from that workflow step and see what, if anything is in that node.
